# Gradle 'run' Task Fails: "Directory does not contain a Gradle build"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, directory, build.gradle

**Question:**
I'm facing an issue when trying to run my Gradle-based Java project using the gradle run command. I encounter the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Directory '/path/to/project' does not contain a Gradle build.

A Gradle build should contain a 'settings.gradle' or 'settings.gradle.kts' file in its root directory. It may also contain a 'build.gradle' or 'build.gradle.kts' file.

To create a new Gradle build in this directory, run 'gradle init'.

For more information about the 'init' task, please refer to [Gradle Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/build_init_plugin.html).

For more details on creating a Gradle build, please refer to [Gradle Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html).

 * Try:
> Run `gradle init` to create a new Gradle build in this directory.
> Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace.
> Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.
> Get more help at [Gradle Help](https://help.gradle.org).
```

**Problem Description:**
I'm trying to run a Java project using Gradle, and my project structure seems to be correct with a build.gradle file in the root directory. However, when I run gradle run, I encounter the error mentioned above.

**Additional Information:**

```
/path/to/project/
├── build.gradle
├── src/
│   └── main/
│       └── java/
│           └── WizardTD/
│               └── build.gradle
                └── App.java
```

- Gradle Version: 8.3

**Steps Taken:**

1. Navigated to the project's root directory.
2. Checked that a **'build.gradle'** file exists.
3. Ran **'gradle run'**.

**Expected Behavior:**
The gradle run task should execute the Java application located in Main.java.

**Actual Behavior:**
The gradle run task fails with the error mentioned above.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully run my Java project using Gradle. Thank you!

Comment: I think your gradle may be set wrong, please search how to use gradle in vscode. Or show more details about your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I would delete the build.gradle file, and initialize the project again with gradle with `gradle init`, try reloading the project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Though this one doesn't explain much, it helped me. I had a build.gradle in my project, but Android Studio didn't recognize it. I also saw this in the interface marking every folder as a generated code folder and file. So within Android Studio and its gradle interface I ran `gradle init`.